# Is "Mandation" a valid word?

Tags: confusables

Is *mandation* a valid word? If it is, then what are its proper uses?

I have heard people using this as a synonym to *mandate*; however, I am not exactly sure that it is a valid word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OED has a reference to it, though they clearly state that it is rare. But far from being a *neologism* the OED example is from1867.

> *Sc. Obs. rare.*
>
> Etymology: f. *mandate* *v.*: see *‑ation*.
>
> The action of committing a speech, etc., to memory.
>
> 1867   J. Macfarlane *Mem. T. Archer* i. 15  — Some of the most
> acceptable ministers of the Gospel have been known to regard
> ‘mandation’ as a process of slow murder.

Comment: +1 nice finding. *Mandation*:https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mandation&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmandation%3B%2Cc0

Comment: "mandation" appears today, 16-July-2021, in a statement by an NHS "boss"  (quoted by the Guardian in the Editions app) with the meaning of "compulsion" as applied to vaccinations.  Perhaps the word is due for a new lease of life.

Answer (score -4):

It’s a horrible bastardised word made up by people when they want to turn a noun to a verb “to mandate” and then create actions from that.
Why not us ‘compulsion’in the context of a requirement??

Comment: Because a *mandate* is not the same thing as a *compulsion*? "I have a compulsion to spend money" does not mean "I have a mandate to spend money."

Comment: Mandation means the act, mandate the result.